# Overflow:hidden not working in safari browser

Tags: safari, mobile-safari

I applied `Overflow:hidden` to `<body> and <html>` tags to stop scrolling of page when popup element is clicked this property working fine for me in almost every browser but not in Safari I googled for this solution but cannot find a solution to this so please someone help me in solving this thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Could you try adding the overflow to the Body and the HTML tag?

```
html,
body {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: I added for body tag do I need to add for html tag too??

Comment: I don't have a computer with safari installed right now, but that might be the case. Could you give it a try?

Comment: hey thanks this worked but only in desktop safari in mobile devices and tablets it is being scrolled still :( any solution for this

Comment: For mobile devices, can you try adding relative positioning to the body? Might be needed to add it to the HTML aswell.

Comment: No tried adding position:relative but that doesn't bite the dust any other solutions?

Comment: `ontouchmove` do you have any idea about this ??

Comment: Don't know that property. I'm sorry. I was hoping that I could help you more.

Comment: That's ok no problem thanks for helping me atleast for desktop version :)