# Javascript touch event not working in Mobile Safari

Tags: javascript, iframe, overflow, addeventlistener

I am trying to restrict user to scroll if they touch on an iframe. So, if they touch on body, they can scroll.

Wondering why below code works fine in Mobile Chrome, but not working in Mobile Safari. Any way to fix this for safari?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
        <style>
            .overflowHidden {
                position:relative;
                overflow-y:hidden;
            }
            .overflowAuto {
                -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
                overflow: auto;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <section>
            <p>hello</p><p>hello</p><p>hello</p><p>hello</p><p>hello</p><p>hello</p><p>hello</p>
            <iframe id="appSimulator" style="background: #000000;" width="189px" height="400px" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
            <p>hello</p><p>hello</p><p>hello</p><p>hello</p><p>hello</p><p>hello</p><p>hello</p>
        </section>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            document.body.addEventListener('touchstart', function(){
                document.body.style.overflow="auto";
                $('body').removeClass('overflowHidden');
                $('body').addClass('overflowAuto');
            }, false)
            document.body.addEventListener('touchend', function(){
                document.body.style.overflow="hidden";
                $('body').removeClass('overflowAuto');
                $('body').addClass('overflowHidden');
            }, false)
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

EDIT

Example for Mobile Chrome - This is what I want in Safari mobile

[image]

Thanks.

EDIT 2

Thank you for the help from muecas.

Here is the current result from Safari Mobile

[image]

Current Code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
        <style>
            body {
                -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
            }
            .iframeContainer, iframe {
                width: 189px;
                height: 405px;
            }
            .iframeContainer {
                overflow: auto;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <section>
            <p>hello</p><p>hello</p><p>hello</p><p>hello</p><p>hello</p><p>hello</p><p>hello</p>
            <div class="iframeContainer">
                <iframe id="appSimulator" src="https://appetize.io/embed/keyyyyyyy?device=iphone5s&scale=50&autoplay=false&orientation=portrait&deviceColor=black&language=zh-Hant" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
            </div>
            <p>hello</p><p>hello</p><p>hello</p><p>hello</p><p>hello</p><p>hello</p><p>hello</p>
        </section>
    </body>
</html>
```

if I set `.iframeContainer { overflow: hidden; }`

[image]

Comment: That code, if managed to get it working, will prevent all scrolling on the page, no matter if you touch the iframe or not. `touch` on the iframe will not trigger `touch` in the main html. So the question is, the problem is not overflowing the `html` or hook to iframe events to prevent scroll? Or both?

Comment: @muecase When I try to test this code in mobile with Chrome browser, the body view would not scroll if I touch on the iFrame and scroll up or down. But when I do this in mobile with Safari, nothing happens like just scroll up or down with no event. The problem I am hitting is I have a scroll view inside iFrame. Here is the thing I am trying to embed. https://appetize.io/  When I try to scroll their simulator,  only body would scroll. The view in simulator (iFrame) does not work.

Comment: The container html must be scrollable? Cause is your example in Chrome you can't scroll the main html either.

Comment: In chrome mobile, I can scroll. Please see my edit

Comment: Thanks for the graphic example of what to achieve. I’ll try my best to help you out.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Stuck in here for a few days already.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The main problem with Safari iOS is that the `iframe` tag is treated as some sort of responsive element, and will act strange to its size, and contained element (loaded HTML) sizes. I tested using an `iframe` with real content, so it will be fully scrollable. Using the same code as in you example, Safari iOS showed the `iframe` with full height of the contained html content event with a `width` and `height` defined.

To solve the problem you need to include the `iframe` in a `block` container, and then set the block container size (`width` and `height`) and `overflow` to `auto`, and add the vendor attribute to the body to allow the `iframe` to be scrolled properly. Also, dont forget to set the iframe as scrollable.

You can discard the `js` implementation.

I tested this on every desktop browser, Safari iOS and Mobile Chrome.

You may also want to check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23083462/how-to-get-an-iframe-to-be-responsive-in-ios-safari) when the responsive content inside an iframe is discussed.

Hope it helps.

Main `html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <style>
        body {
            -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
        }
        .iframeContainer, iframe {
            width: 200px;
            height: 200px;
        }
        .iframeContainer {
            overflow: auto;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <section>
        <p>hello</p><p>hello</p><p>hello</p><p>hello</p><p>hello</p><p>hello</p><p>hello</p>
        <div class="iframeContainer">
            <iframe id="appSimulator" frameborder="0" src="scrolling.html" scrolling="yes"></iframe>
        </div>
        <p>hello</p><p>hello</p><p>hello</p><p>hello</p><p>hello</p><p>hello</p><p>hello</p>
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

Loaded `iframe`:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <style>
        body {
            background-color: black;
            color: white;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <p>hello</p>
    <p>hello</p>
    <p>hello</p>
    <p>hello</p>
    <p>hello</p>
    <p>hello</p>
    <p>hello</p>
    <p>hello</p>
    <p>hello</p>
    <p>hello</p>
    <p>hello</p>
    <p>hello</p>
    <p>hello</p>
    <p>hello</p>
    <p>hello</p>
    <p>hello</p>
    <p>hello</p>
    <p>hello</p>
    <p>hello</p>
    <p>hello</p>
    <p>hello</p>
    <p>hello</p>
    <p>hello</p>
    <p>hello</p>
    <p>hello</p>
    <p>hello</p>
    <p>hello</p>
    <p>hello</p>
    <p>hello</p>
    <p>hello</p>
    <p>hello</p>
    <p>hello</p>
    <p>hello</p>
    <p>hello</p>
    <p>hello</p>
    <p>hello</p>
    <p>hello</p>
    <p>hello</p>
    <p>hello</p>
    <p>hello</p>
    <p>hello</p>
    <p>hello</p>
    <p>hello</p>
    <p>hello</p>
    <p>hello</p>
    <p>hello</p>
    <p>hello</p>
    <p>hello</p>
    <p>hello</p>
    <p>hello</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for all the help. I think it is really close. The only problem I have now is the ```appSimulator``` would bounce if I scroll up or down.

Comment: I am thinking the bounce comes from the third-party ```src```

Comment: @PakHoCheung bounce? Can i see an example of that?

Comment: thank you for your help. I uploaded a gif for what I see in Safari mobile

Comment: @PakHoCheung so the requested behavior is achieved. You can scroll the main page and the iframe too. What’s missing?

Comment: The content of the app inside the simulator is scrollable. So it is so rare when I scroll the content, I can see a bounce at the same time. Let me show you the content

Comment: @PakHoCheung I thought that the iframe should be scrollable.

Comment: @muecase Updated the new gif. If I set the iframe to be not scrollable, it also means I cannot scroll the content of simulator?

Comment: @PakHoCheung the problem with the bouncing scroll is that, in order to remove it, you need to hace access to the contained page on the iframe, to apply some hacks there. Otherwise is not possible. have you tried `overlofw: hidden` on the div that contains the iframe?

Comment: Do you think if I know the iframe's position like its width or height, I can check if user touch on the iframe's position, I can just disable scroll on body?

Comment: @PakHoCheung well, not on Safari iOS; it will not fire the touch event over an iframe. :-( So the embeded app will never scroll?

Comment: It will scroll but also scroll the whole body haha @muecas

Comment: @PakHoCheung how's that? You cant scroll iframe and body at the same time. Only if you reach top or bottom. Is the expected behavior.

Comment: please see the last gif

Comment: @PakHoCheung ok, one thing i don't get, whats the point of preventing the scroll over iframe, if the iframe has no scroll? Or am i missing something?

Comment: It looks more professional if I scroll the iframe and the iframe doesn't have any bounce but the content of the simulator can be scrolled. @muecas

Comment: @PakHoCheung i know, but the problem is that, if you cant control the iframe content, then you can't do it.  You would need to remove the overflow or prevent touch move inside the iframe in order to do that. From outside the iframe (and with the source iframe out of control - loaded from another domain -) that's not possible.

Comment: oh i see. thank you for the help. But, I am wondering why I can do it in Chrome Mobile, but cant do it in Safari Mobile. Is it because as you said the iframe tag of safari is treated as some sort of responsive element. @muecas

Comment: @PakHoCheung the problem is that on Safari, the touch event does not bind to the container html, so it's not fired on you html, only in the app html. I testes several times :-(

Comment: such a pain. Anyways, thanks for all the help. you are the best person I see in here:)

Comment: @PakHoCheung sorry i couldn't fully solve your problem :-(

Comment: @meucas It is ok. At least I get one more option of what user can see haha

Comment: @PakHoCheung i guess i will not get the bounty haha i need to try harder ;-)

Answer (score 2):

It seems touch event works well but overflow is not.
I am not sure what your html looks like, however you can try these:

1. hidden:
   `body {
       /* position can be fixed */
       position:relative;
       overflow-y:hidden;
   }`
2. auto:
   `body {
       -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
       overflow: auto;
   }`

Comment: How can I write -webkit-overflow-scrolling in Javascript? Thanks.

Comment: You can set them as class style, like `.overflow-hidden{position:relative;overflow-y:hidden;}`. Then what you need is to use `$('body').removeClass('overflow-auto')` and `$('body').addClass('overflow-hidden')`.

Comment: Still not work. Updated the whole html file that produces this issue in Safari mobile.

Comment: Your problem is that **Overflow:hidden not working in safari browser** which there is a some question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28407499/overflowhidden-not-working-in-safari-browser). Suggestion from him is to add the same class to html tag. I hope it will help you.

Comment: That post also cannot fix MOBILE safari. Anyways, thank you for the help